# WCF using it's own web.config

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I have a MVC3 app that is calling a WCF Service Application.  The WCF Service App has its own web.config file (comes when you create the project automatically).  In this .config I added an appSetting section with key to retrieve.

When I run the MVC app and it calls the WCF svc and the svc cannot see this appsettings value.  If I move the appSettings section over to the MVC web.config the service application sees the value.

I would expect this from a calling application if it were a Winform or client based application calling a DLL but not where I have 2 separate apps where I actually want separate configuration files.

For example, I want to configure unity in my web services to perform dependency injection.  I don't want the calling web application to know or have to define these values.  The service should have them.

Comment: How is the WCF service being called and where is it hosted? It should definitely be using its own config.

Comment: I am running this fromm within Visual Studio at this time, so the service and the MVC app are both running through Cassini/default web server with VS 2010.  The service has its own static port to run under....I'm stumped I thought it should be using its own config too.

Comment: I am not 100% on what is going on without seeing the exact setup, but if you publish your WCF and run it with IIS instead of VS 2010 I doubt you will see any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I had was with the Unity configuration in the MVC app.  Originally I had been pointing at a class library for my services layer, I swapped this over to use WCF.  When I did this I left in the old type registrations which unity resolved and caused it to look at the new WCF project (same namespaces/class names) as a class library instead of using the endpoints that I registered.

Ripped out those specific class registrations leaving just the interfaces and endpoints and it worked like a charm.